# Close HamburgerMenu with slide gesture

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to implement a slide gesture to open/close the [hamburguer menu control](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/HamburgerMenu), but I'm having trouble closing the menu with version 1.5.1 of the control. With version 1.4.1 I close the menu this way:

```
var paneGrid = HamburgerMenu.FindDescendantByName("PaneGrid") as Grid; 
paneGrid.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX; 
paneGrid.ManipulationCompleted += OnPaneGridManipulationCompleted;

private void OnPaneGridManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e) { 
    if (e.Cumulative.Translation.X < -50) { 
        HamburgerMenu.IsPaneOpen = false; 
    } 
}
```

But with version 1.5.1 the listviews take all space in the control and "OnPaneGridManipulationCompleted" does not get fired... any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting both `HorizontalScrollMode` and `VerticalScrollMode` to `Disabled` on the `ListView`'s inner `ScrollViewer` to let touch input bypass it.

Since the default value of `HorizontalScrollMode` is already `Disabled`. You just need to manually set the `VerticalScrollMode` as below

```
if (HamburgerMenuControl.FindDescendantByName("ButtonsListView") is ListView listView)
{
    ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollMode(listView, ScrollMode.Disabled);
}
```

The side effect is that you can no longer scroll the `ListView` vertically. But generally you wouldn't want that(bad design) anyway.

You might also be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108362/adding-a-swipe-gesture-to-open-splitview-pane/32110867#32110867) of mine. :)